# How should we handle equivalent tags, like gm vs. dm?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are already tags that may (or may not be) equivalents. How do we want to handle gm vs. dm and online vs. online-resources for example?

Comment: Note: there is currently no [dm] tag in the system, so I can't suggest a synonym, although if the [dm] tag isn't being used it doesn't matter so that's all good.

Comment: If you see a synonym that's needed and you don't have sufficient rep yet, please feel free to point it out as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do believe there is a way to make synonyms for tags. That way if someone searches for [GM] they will get [DM] results as well.

Comment: This appears to be correct, although it may take a moderator to do it.

Comment: @Bryant, No, just the top users in the tag, as stated [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dd4.0&sort=info&pagesize=15)

Comment: That needs a good number of users with a lot of rep, there's going to be revert wars and bitching for a good while until DM/GM gets sorted.

Answer (score 2):

I think [dm] should be blacklisted (I dunno if we can do that in beta) as it's kind of DnD specific, while this site is RPG-oriented, not DnD oriented.

If someone tries to use [dm] it should give them a message informing them to use [gm] instead.

Sunno about the rest...

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can just edit the tags. I have arrogantly taken it upon myself to purge all the [dm] tags (changing them into [gm] tags) -- if this is wrong of me let me know and I'll stop. But it seems like a decent solution for now.

Comment: I think the synonym route is better. You are going to get a lot of D&D players on here and you are going to have a fun time changing all those tags after a while.

Comment: Synonyms would be better, there may well be cases where DM is more accurate than GM

Answer (score 0):

I like synonyms; also frankly DM vs GM serves useful segmentation; you know a "DM" question is going to be about D&D and cover certain concerns that are often different from "GM" questions from the broader game world.

Comment: I agree that the term DM, GM, ZM, hell Referee even all have their places. The synonym seems to be the best way to go, rolling it all into one, while the actual tag used is indicative of the subject being discussed.

Comment: If it's tagged for D&D then you know it's going to be a D&D question.  So tagging GM and D&D is the equivalent of a DM tag but useful to GM's and D&Ders too.